# jquery for loop returning every array element

Tags: jquery

This is a question involving a loop that I've seen asked a lot, i just can't seem to find anything that helps my situation.

I've built a very simple app which calls the Instagram API when the user inputs a hashtag. The below displays the images and assigns the URL to the image.

```
    for ( i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
        imageDisplay = response.data[i].images.low_resolution.url;
        imageUrl = response.data[i].link;
        $instagram.append( '<img src="' + imageDisplay + '"/>');
        $('img').wrap("<a href="+ imageUrl + "></a>");
    };
})
```

Here's where the problem is, every image sends the user through to the last url result. I need to return the result with each loop but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be in 
`$('img').wrap("<a href="+ imageUrl + "></a>");`
you select all `img` tags this way.
The correct way would be

`$instagram.append( '<a href="+ imageUrl + "><img src="' + imageDisplay + '"/></a>');`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a jQuery whiz, but I think this code:

```
$('img').wrap("<a href="+ imageUrl + "></a>");
```

... has the effect of wrapping your link around EVERY image tag.  So every time you go through the loop, you're re-wrapping all your images.

You need to identify the particular image tag you just created, and wrap your link around that.

No doubt someone will correct me if I've got this wrong.